# Exception when client sends message to server

Tags: netty

I am using netty 3.2.7.
When I send a message (contained in DAOMessage) from the client to the server on the same computer it works correctly.

If I do exactly the same but have the client and server on different computers I get the following exception. The server is complaining that it can't find the DAOMessage. Surely all it needs is its reference which is passed to it in the channel / pipeline.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

```
31-Dec-2011 12:59:17 org.jboss.netty.server.SecureServerHandler exceptionCaught
WARNING: Unexpected exception from downstream.
java.io.InvalidClassException: failed to read class descriptor
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1732)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.serialization.ObjectDecoder.decode(ObjectDecoder.java:129)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:282)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:216)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:302)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:321)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:299)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:216)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:274)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:261)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:351)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:282)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:202)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.acm.domain.DAOMessage
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.serialization.ClassLoaderClassResolver.resolve(ClassLoaderClassResolver.java:35)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.serialization.CachingClassResolver.resolve(CachingClassResolver.java:43)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.serialization.CompactObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(CompactObjectInputStream.java:62)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1565)
    ... 19 more
31-Dec-2011 12:59:17 org.jboss.netty.server.SecureServerHandler handleUpstream
INFO: [id: 0x013936e1, /127.0.0.1:49318 :> /127.0.0.1:1234] DISCONNECTED
31-Dec-2011 12:59:17 org.jboss.netty.server.SecureServerHandler handleUpstream
INFO: [id: 0x013936e1, /127.0.0.1:49318 :> /127.0.0.1:1234] UNBOUND
31-Dec-2011 12:59:17 org.jboss.netty.server.SecureServerHandler handleUpstream
INFO: [id: 0x013936e1, /127.0.0.1:49318 :> /127.0.0.1:1234] CLOSED
```

Comment: Did you provide the jar/class or whatever these files are named once compiled also on the server? The exception says: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.acm.domain.DAOMessage which basically mens that the server cann't find that class. It needs the class because otherwise it doesn't know how to desrialize the object it receives over the line.